# Is the interest on EE series US Savings Bonds accrual dates prorated If I cash in just before an accrual date?

Tags: united-states, interest, savings-bonds

I have several EE series US savings bonds which I would like to cash, they were all given to me on the same date in different years, and I calculated the interest online, the calculator said that based on the info I provided the accrual date was in one month.

Does this mean that I should wait one more month to accrue one more set of interest before cashing the bonds, or is the interest added in such a way that it does not matter when I cash them?

Comment: If you are not in a hurry, wait. If you are in a hurry, cash them right away. Unless the bonds have large face value, the difference in what you will get will be quite small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many years ago I had EE bonds, I had originally bought them via payroll deduction.  They were credited with the interest every 6 months. When I decided to cash out of them to maximize the return  I took the ones that had just had the interested credited to the bank. I took a new batch every month for 6 months.

If your bonds work the same way and you cash them out a month before the interest credit you are giving up 5 months of interest. If that is a negligible amount then there is no harm, but if you can wait you can capture that last bit of interest.